# How do I find the 1st character after the nth separation space

Tags: regex, vim

I have a text file composed by lines such that (example):

```
Oct 10 21:56:21 2015 QST  Aldrin completed quest 'has proven their patience & kindness in their path to becoming a ranger.'
```

Suppose that I want to land always on the character `c` of word `completed` above using Vim.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using normal commands, just do `06f<space>l` (with `<space>` replaced with a real spacebar press) to place your cursor at the right column.

If you you want to get the end of the message into a variable:

```
:let mess = matchstr(getline('.'), '^\(.\{-} \)\{5}\zs.*')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if I understand you correctly, but this seems to work:

```
/\%(^\%([^ ]* \)\{6\}\)\@<=.
```

Replace the 6 by the number of groupy you like to skip.